# Have any of you tried Soundtorch? 

Tags: design, management, data, workflow

Its an amazingly intuitive sound finder.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMLylqa5Gck

Load in all of your sounds and it automatically sorts them by similarity.
Pretty damn amazing. 
They just released a public beta test.

Enjoy

http://soundtorch.com/Default.aspx

Comment: That is HELLA cool.

Comment: could you please share an archive of this software's install files ? The source website is partially down and the original setup.exe found on the wayback machine points to a missing other file. Thanks a lot if you can help !!!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the beta, and after a conversation with the developer, it doesn't work so well with WinXP yet, but they are working on it.  I'm going to be upgrading to Windows 7 in the next week or so, so I'll give an update once I'm able to play with it.

Comment: When you were talking with the developer, did they mention any plans for a Mac version any time soon?


Comment: A Mac version didn't come up in the conversation.  It seems to be a hot topic though!

Answer (score 2):

I really hope it makes all those sputtering and morphing sounds when you use it and there isn't any additional sound design done to the video demo. Would be wicked to use it for doing sound design itself.

Comment: After messing about with it for the past hour or so I gotta say that this is a really wicked accidental tool for sound design. It's like having a giant x/y DJ mixer. Morphing through sounds, making them grow, contract, etc. It's pretty wicked in Parallels with the Mac Magic Trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty cool...quite similar to Diego Schwartz's [CatArt](http://imtr.ircam.fr/imtr/CataRT) built with Max/MSP and FTM - a wonderful tool/instrument

Answer (score 1):

despite the obvious fun you could have just panning over groups of sounds to create, it seems like it could be a fresh approach to finding the right one off sounds (kicks, snares) when writing electronic music.

Comment: +1 I was just thinking the same thing! My percussion library is pretty large and cluttered, this seems like the perfect tool to make sense of it all! I look forward to giving it a shot when I get home!


Answer (score 0):

Great! I would love to run it through our 160.000 sounds archive. I really, really hope they make a mac version!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it'd normally slow me down, but as far as those roadblock moments (particularly with music production) could be very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Quite buggy atm, but loving the interface and design! Using this one a lot at work!